# Unable to upload large file to mail draft using MS Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the error: "Stream doesn't support reading", when I am trying to upload large files in chunks to a mail draft using Microsoft Graph. I have tried doing the same with MemoryStream, this gives the same result.

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2, Microsoft Graph 3.27.0, Microsoft Graph Core 1.24.0.

```cs
    public static async Task AttachFileAsync(
         GraphServiceClient graphClient,
         string draftMessageId,
         List<Models.MailAttachment> mailAttachments)
        {
            foreach (var mailattachment in mailAttachments)
            {
                if (mailattachment.Data.LongLength >= 3000000
                         && mailattachment.Data.LongLength <= 150000000)
                {
                    var attachmentItem = new AttachmentItem
                    {
                        Name = mailattachment.Name,
                        Size = mailattachment.Data.LongLength
                    };
                    var uploadSession = await graphClient
                        .Me
                        .Messages[$"{draftMessageId}"]
                        .Attachments
                        .CreateUploadSession(attachmentItem)
                        .Request()
                        .PostAsync();

                    int chunkSize = 320 * 1024;
                    try
                    {
                        using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(attachmentItem.Name, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            var uploadProvider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, graphClient, stream, chunkSize);
                            var chunks = uploadProvider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
                            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

                            int iterations = 0;
                            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
                            {
                                var chunkRequestResponse = await uploadProvider
                                    .GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(chunk, exceptions);
                                if (!chunkRequestResponse.UploadSucceeded)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Upload of mailAttachment failed.");
                                }
                                iterations++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My stacktrace is:

```
StackTrace  "   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Graph.UploadChunkRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Graph.UploadChunkRequest.<PutAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Graph.ChunkedUploadProvider.<GetChunkRequestResponseAsync>d__18.MoveNext()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n
   at graph_tutorial.Helpers.GraphHelper.<AttachFileAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Flemming\\source\\repos\\msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp\\graph-tutorial\\Helpers\\GraphHelper.cs:line 176"   string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `System.IO.File.OpenRead(attachmentItem.Name)` instead of `System.IO.File.Open(attachmentItem.Name, FileMode.Open)`.

`OpenRead` will return a read-only `FilStream`.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still getting "Stream doesn't support reading".